# All toilets whining when refilling!

Tags: plumbing

I've seen lots of posts that speak of a single toilet whining, but one day, a few weeks ago, **all of our toilets on the middle and upper floor (3 toilets) started whining when the tank is refilling**.

If I turn on the cold water faucet next to the toilet (or the shower) the whining immediately stops!

So I thought this may be a water pressure issue. .. but our pressure doesn't seem to be very high. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a pressure issue to me since multiple toilets and when you open the tap the noise stops. Unless plumbing work has just been done that could have debris plugging only the upstairs fill valves I would think your pressure has changed.